# Where can I find the custom bone in version 2.8?

Tags: rigging, versions

When I import a character created in version 2.79 of Blender to version 2.8, I do not see a custom bone. I am currently using version 2.80.31 of Blender.

Some characters seem to have a custom bone, but there are more characters that do not.

Do I have to wait for the official 2.8 version?

Or is there another solution? I tried Google but I could not find the right answer for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, to custom your bone you need to create the shape with a mesh, then select the bone you want to custom and in the Properties panel > Bone > Viewport Display , choose the mesh as Custom Object

Comment: I lacked my English skills and I did not understand your writing well. Where can I find relevant tutorials?

Comment: I'm going to make an illustrated answer

Comment: Could you please share your original 2.79 file? The strange thing is that when you append the armature in 2.8 it should also append the original objects that are used to custom your bones...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xz7hHVwNhpmSCeg3xvn0k_QuRKnKm_Fl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Collection 11, the one with your bones, was hidden, I don’t know why as I don't know a lot yet about how the switch from 2.79 layers to 2.8 collections works, but anyway unhide it:

[image]

About custom bones, how to create custom bones:

- In *Object* mode, create the object that is supposed to be used as the bone's custom shape, for example a sphere.
- Select your armature, switch to *Pose* mode, select the bone you want to custom.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Viewport Display*, enable *Wireframe* so that your custom bone will be displayed as a wireframe, and choose your sphere as *Custom Object*.
- Now your bone is displayed as a sphere in *Pose* and *Object* mode.
- You can modify the original sphere object (edit, rotate, scale...), it will be directly replicated on the custom bone. But you can scale in the same *Viewport Display* menu.

[image]